# jquery .load() function recrusive

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have this code which is load the .aspx element the #maincontent div - it works but when I click another button witch is load the page same  #maincontent div I see the console a lot of deal.aspx and ta.aspx loaded.

How can I do the one click one page load? or how to clear the recursive stack.

jquery code:

```
$("#tre").click(function () {
  $("#mainContent").load("subMenu1/deal.aspx");
});

$("#tra").click(function () {
  $("#mainContent").load("subMenu1/ta.aspx");
});
```

C# :

```
<div runat="server" id="mainContent"></div>
```

Comment: It triggers not because of it is being recursive, it triggers because you are doing a full postback on the button click (send all data, receive all data, executing again all your javascript). You may want to add to the question your button related code. We dont know if you are working with MVC or webforms, and probably the answers would differ (MVC has partial views, webform doesn't)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm working with web form

Comment: Can I block the full postback in js ? I tried the preventDefault method, but it didn't work.

Comment: In webforms there are some alternatives, for example, place the button in an UpdatePanel so the button does automatically a partial postback, or use jquery's ajax function to manually call the page and do whatever you need with the response. Goggle a bit those things, look at how they are used and try to implement any of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, but I made a mistake.

So When I call the .aspx I didn't notice that aspx file has got attached script file, what is include again this page calls

> 

```
$("#tre").click(function () {  
 $("#mainContent").load("subMenu1/deal.aspx"); 
});
 $("#tra").click(function () {  
 $("#mainContent").load("subMenu1/ta.aspx"); 
});
```

**> this caused the multiple page call. Now I fix the problem. Thanks for the help. It was very useful.**